# Php: output all content in the column not only the first item

Tags: php

I have two columns in my database, year and content i want to group the content by year (i have a lot of content and many years not only 2015 and 2016 as the example )

so i'll have this output in html

```html
<div class="all">
  <div class="2016">
    2016
      <div class="content_2016">
          All the content of the column that is in the same ligne as 2016 in the database
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="2015">
    2015
      <div class="content_2015">
          All the content of the column that is in the same ligne as 2015 in the database
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
<?php
 $query = "SELECT * FROM publi where pub_type=0 order by pub_year DESC, pub_publi ";
 $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

 $previous =0;
 while ($val = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {

  if ($previous <> $val['pub_year'])
  {
   $previous = $val['pub_year'];
   $year = $previous;

  echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#';
  echo $year;
  echo '">';
  echo $year;
  echo '</button>';
  echo '<div id="';
  echo $year;
  echo '" class="collapse">';



   $Temp = highlight("person1",$val['pub_publi'],"0000FF");
   $Temp = highlight("person2",$Temp,"0000FF");
   $Temp = highlight("person3",$Temp,"0000FF");
   $Temp = highlight("person4",$Temp,"0000FF");
   $Temp = highlight("person5",$Temp,"0000FF");
   $Temp = highlight("person6",$Temp,"0000FF");
   $Temp = highlight("person7",$Temp,"0000FF");
   $Temp = highlight("person8",$Temp,"0000FF");
   $Temp = highlight("person9",$Temp,"0000FF");
   $Temp = highlight("person10",$Temp,"0000FF");


   echo '<a target=blank href="http://www.test.com/query.f?term=' . $val['pub_pubmed'] . '";)><img border="0" src="img/test.gif" align=MIDDLE alt="Search in  for ' . $val['pub_publi'] . '"></a>';
     echo $Temp;
    echo '</div>';

   
     }
   
   
    }



?>
```

It is outputing the years right

2016

2015

2014

etc...

but it is only showing the first ligne of each year not all the content for each year.

Comment: There is _no_ code outside the `if` that checks for a different year, so of course there will only be content printed when the year changes compared to the previous row.

Comment: and what can i do to make it work ? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked for me.

```
    <?php
        $previous = false;
        while ($val = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            // when group is changing, end previous and start new
            if ($previous <> $val['pub_year']) {

                // end previous group html markup
                if ($previous !== false) {
                    echo '</div>';
                }

                $previous = $val['pub_year'];
                $year = $previous;

                echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#' . $year . '>' . $year . '</button>';
                echo '<div id="' . $year . '" class="collapse">';
            }

            // always output data inside group
            $Temp = highlight("person1",$val['pub_publi'],"0000FF");
            $Temp = highlight("person2",$Temp,"0000FF");
            $Temp = highlight("person3",$Temp,"0000FF");
            $Temp = highlight("person4",$Temp,"0000FF");
            $Temp = highlight("person5",$Temp,"0000FF");
            $Temp = highlight("person6",$Temp,"0000FF");
            $Temp = highlight("person7",$Temp,"0000FF");
            $Temp = highlight("person8",$Temp,"0000FF");
            $Temp = highlight("person9",$Temp,"0000FF");
            $Temp = highlight("person10",$Temp,"0000FF");

            echo $Temp . '<br>';
        }

        // end last group html markup
        if ($previous !== false) {
            echo '</div>';
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this** updated code:

```
<?php
    $output='';

    $query1 = "SELECT pub_year FROM publi where pub_type=0 GROUP BY pub_year order by pub_year DESC";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $query1);

    while ($val1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
    {
        $year = $val1['pub_year'];
        $query2 = "SELECT * FROM publi where pub_year=$year AND pub_type=0 order by pub_year DESC, pub_publi ";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $query2);

        $output.=$year.'<br>';  // storing each year value one time

        while ($val2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
        {
            $output.=$val2['pub_type'].', '.$val2['pub_publi'].'<br><br>';
        }
    }
    echo $output;
?>
```

**Sample Output:**

```
2016
[pub_type_1], [pub_publi_1]
[pub_type_2], [pub_publi_2]

2015
[pub_type_1], [pub_publi_1]
[pub_type_2], [pub_publi_2]
```

Comment: I tried this too but what i want excatly is to output the year one time so i can use it in the accordion that will be sorted by year 2016,2015 etc.. but it's not working as expected because either the div to open the content is assigned to the first ligne 'value' inside the column or only the first ligne 'value' appears and not the others